# Having trouble with simple implementation of flatten in SML

Tags: sml

I'm trying to implement flatten : 'a list list -> 'a list list in SML.
I thought this should be relatively straight forward with higher order functions. My implementation is

```
val flatten = List.reduce (op @) []
```

However I'm getting a bizarre error message: "append.sml:1.6-1.36 Warning: type vars not generalized because of
value restriction are instantiated to dummy types (X1,X2,...)". Thus when I try to flatten an int list list I get a type error:

:> flatten [[1,2],[3]];

stdIn:2.1-2.20 Error: operator and operand don't agree [literal]

operator domain: **?.X1 list list**
operand:         **int list list**
  in expression:
    flatten ((1 :: 2 :: nil) :: (3 :: nil) :: nil)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message hints, you ran into the *value restriction* -- see [here](http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction) for an explanation. The solution is very simple: just "eta-expand" your definition, i.e., make the parameter explicit instead of relying on partial application:

```
fun flatten xs = List.reduce op@ [] xs
```